# How to integrate IGDB with react native fetch

Tags: reactjs, react-native, post, get, fetch-api

am trying to fetch data from IGDB and am just getting ids for display. Hear is my code. i have tried making the call in postman and its working. am getinh all the data but on app intergration is where am only geting ids

```
export const getIgdbGames = async url => {
    const API_URL = `https://api.igdb.com/v4/${url}`


    let response = await fetch(
        API_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Client-ID': 'nnwcbehargneibi9tyuxrpcnc3jfoj',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer 4jkb50c4yzquwiaz89bw0t2rxi10lc',
        },
        
       data: "fields name;"
       //data: "fields id,artworks,bundles,category,checksum,collection,cover.*,created_at,first_release_date,follows,game_engines.*,game_modes.*,genres.*,hypes,keywords.*,multiplayer_modes,name,parent_game, platforms.*, platforms.platform_logo.*,player_perspectives.*,popularity,rating,rating_count,screenshots.*, slug,standalone_expansions,status,storyline,summary,tags,time_to_beat,total_rating,total_rating_count,updated_at,url,version_parent,version_title,videos.*;sort popularity desc;"
    }
    );
    response = response.json();
    return response;
};
```

this is the card am using in my UI and loading the igdb data

```
const GameCard = props => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [igdbGames, setigdbGames] = useState([]);
  const { colors } = useTheme();
  

  useEffect(() => {
    const getIgdb = async () => {
      const data = await getIgdbGames(props.url);
      setigdbGames(data);
      setLoading(false);
      console.log(data);
    };
    getIgdb();
  }, []);


  const displayGames = ({ item }, props) => {
 
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{ color: colors.text }}>
          <Text style={{ margin: 10, color: colors.text }}>
            {item.id}
          </Text>
          <Text >
            {item.name} hello
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      

      {loading ? (
        <Loader />
      ) : (
       

          <FlatList
            key={'*'}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index + "_" + item.id.toString()}
            data={igdbGames}
            //horizontal
            renderItem={item => displayGames(item, props)}
          />
       
      )}
    </View>
```

this my UI

```
  <GameCard
            title="Igdb"
            url="games"
            navigation={props.navigation}
          />
```

this is the response am getting.Please help.
[{"id": 33260}, {"id": 40104}, {"id": 85031}, {"id": 161757}, {"id": 2802}, {"id": 139538}, {"id": 85450}, {"id": 33284}, {"id": 89616}, {"id": 104748}]

Answer (score 0):

I finally realized the problem.

```
body:
    "fields age_ratings,aggregated_rating,aggregated_rating_count,alternative_names,artworks,bundles,category,checksum,collection,cover,created_at,dlcs,expanded_games,expansions,external_games,first_release_date,follows,forks,franchise,franchises,game_engines,game_modes,genres,hypes,involved_companies,keywords,multiplayer_modes,name,parent_game,platforms,player_perspectives,ports,rating,rating_count,release_dates,remakes,remasters,screenshots,similar_games,slug,standalone_expansions,status,storyline,summary,tags,themes,total_rating,total_rating_count,updated_at,url,version_parent,version_title,videos,websites;"
```

**should be Body not data**